# Выдает ошибку когда обращаются к ключу объекта

Tags: javascript

Ошибка в консоли,но все работает
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at personOrCompany
at HTMLButtonElement.handleCompanyBuyCar

```js
function handleCompanyBuyCar() {
    const carsSection = document.getElementById('cars');

    const carId = event.target.getAttribute('data-carId');
    const companyArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company'));
    const parseCarsShop = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cars'));

    const selectedCar = parseCarsShop.find(function (car) {
        return car.id === carId;
    })

    personOrCompany(selectedCar,companyArr,carsSection);
}

function personOrCompany(selectedCar,peopleOrCompanyArr,carsSection) {
    deleteContent();
    const formBuyCar = document.createElement('form');
    const formContent = document.createElement('div');
    const carNamePrice = document.createElement('h2');

    formContent.classList.add('item');
    carNamePrice.classList.add('titleBuyForm');
    formBuyCar.classList.add('content');

    carsSection.appendChild(formBuyCar);
    formBuyCar.appendChild(formContent)
    formContent.appendChild(carNamePrice);

    carNamePrice.innerHTML = `${selectedCar.carName} Price: ${selectedCar.carPrice}$,Choose person:`;

    const peopleArr = localStorage.getItem('people');
    const companyArr = localStorage.getItem('company');
    const checkArr = JSON.stringify(peopleOrCompanyArr);
    
    for(let i = 0; peopleOrCompanyArr.length; i++) {
        const item = document.createElement('p');
        //// ошибка в консоли,но все работает
        item.innerHTML = `${peopleOrCompanyArr[i].name}, Money: ${peopleOrCompanyArr[i].money}$`; 
        //// ошибка в консоли,но все работает
        item.setAttribute('data-carId',selectedCar.id);
        if(checkArr === peopleArr) {
            item.setAttribute('data-peopleId',peopleOrCompanyArr[i].id);
        }
        if(checkArr === companyArr) {
            item.setAttribute('data-companyId',peopleOrCompanyArr[i].id);
        }
        formContent.appendChild(item);
        item.classList.add('name');
        item.addEventListener('click',handleItemBuyCar);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let i = 0; i < peopleOrCompanyArr.length; i++) {
               ^^^^
```