# Почему не работает сортировка?

Tags: javascript

```
"presents": [{
    "id": 61,
    "name": "Дорожный Набор Для Бритья Edwin Jagger Ejlt2M3",
    "price": "4188",
    "brand": "Edwin Jagger",
    "img": "https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/product/2015-11-294-543x543.webp"
  },
  {
    "id": 62,
    "name": "Подарочный набор для бритья Taylor of Old Bond Street Shaving Brush, Mach 3 Razor & Jermyn Street Collection Shaving Cream 150 г",
    "price": "3788",
    "brand": "Old Bond",
    "img": "https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/product-2018/05-2018/Taylor-of-Old-Bond-Street-Shaving-Brush-Mach-3-Razor-Jermyn-Street-Collection-Shaving-Cream-543x543.webp"
  },
  {
    "id": 63,
    "name": "Масло Для Бороды Proraso Hot Oil Beard Treatment 4 х 17 мл",
    "price": "298",
    "brand": "Proraso",
    "img": "https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/Proraso/maslo-dlja-borodi-proraso-hot-oil-beard-treatment-4-h-17-ml-543x543.webp"
  },
  {
    "id": 64,
    "name": "Маникюрный Набор Унисекс на 6 Предметов Truefitt & Hill Large Manicure Set 6 Piece Tan",
    "price": "4788",
    "brand": "Truefitt & Hill",
    "img": "https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/product/2017-03-truefitt-hill-large-manicure-set-6-piece-tan-543x543.webp"
  },
  {
    "id": 65,
    "name": "Подарочный Набор Muhle Organic Body Care Set",
    "price": "948",
    "brand": "Muhle",
    "img": "https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/product-2019/12-2019/Muhle_Organic_Body_Care_Set-543x543.webp"
  }
]
```

Почему не сортирует по цене `data.sort()`?

```
const radioCheckArr = document.querySelectorAll('.choose-master__radio');
radioCheckArr.forEach((radio) => {
  if (radio.checked && radio.id === 'filter-0') {
    if (dataCategory.length === 0) {
      //exp to cheap
      data.sort((product1, product2) => product1.price > product2.price ? 1 : -1);
      filterData.reverse();
      createCards(data, parent, category);
    } else {
      dataCategory.sort((product1, product2) => product1.price > product2.price ? 1 : -1);
      dataCategory.reverse();
      createCards(dataCategory, parent, category);
    }

  } else if (radio.checked && radio.id === 'filter-1') {
    //cheap to exp
    if (dataCategory.length === 0) {
      data.sort((product1, product2) => product1.price > product2.price ? 1 : -1);
      createCards(data, parent, category);
    } else {
      dataCategory.sort((product1, product2) => product1.price > product2.price ? 1 : -1);
      createCards(dataCategory, parent, category);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Нету совпадений и все равно не правильно работает

Comment: Потому, что сравниваются строки, а не числа

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо,помогло

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143912/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: @Igor А что там нужно сделать?

Comment: @IhorStoner Щелкнуть по "галочке" слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.sort((product1, product2) => product1.price - product2.price);
```

Comment: Что там у JS с переполнением?

Comment: И, кстати, при вычитании строки сами кастанутся к интам

Comment: @AntonShchyrov с переполнением - для разницы цен дожно быть нормально